# Dividing two inputted numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
number1 DWORD   ?
number2 DWORD   ?

prompt1 BYTE    "Enter the number of gallons of gas the car can hold:", 0
prompt2 BYTE    "Enter the number of miles you can drive on a full tank", 0

string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)
resultLxx BYTE  "The miles per gallon your car gets is:", 0
mpg     BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        mov     edx, 0

        input   prompt1, string, 40      ; read ASCII characters 
        atod    string          ; convert to integer
        mov     eax, number1    ; store in memory

        
        input   prompt2, string, 40      ; read ASCII characters  
        atod    string          ; convert to integer
        mov     ebx, number2    ; store in memory
        


        div     ebx ; divide miles by full tank      
        dtoa    mpg, ebx
        
        output  resultLxx, mpg          ; output label and sum


        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

Hello, it is my first day learning assembly and I'm trying to divide these two inputted numbers. It's basically just dividing number2 by number1. I'm a bit confused and wanted to reach out for help on how to write this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear from your description what the problem is. What happens when you run this program? How does that differ from what you expected? Have you read the documentation for those macros that you are using and made sure that you're using them correctly?

Comment: Are you sure `atod` and `input` preserve EDX?  It would make more sense to zero EDX right before `div`, instead of before calling multiple other functions (or macros).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov     eax, number1    ; store in memory
> ...
> mov     ebx, number2    ; store in memory
> ```

On x86, the left operand is the **destination**, the right operand is the **source**.
So to store the output from the *atod* macro (which is probably EAX) you need to write:

```
mov     number1, eax          ; gallons
...
mov     number2, eax          ; miles
```

> ```
> div     ebx ; divide miles by full tank      
> dtoa    mpg, ebx
> ```

In order to get the *miles per gallon*, you need to divide *miles* by *gallon*. Your `div ebx` where EBX contains *number2* that holds the *miles* is doing it the other way. Also, the `dtoa mpg, ebx` macro invokation refers to the EBX register when in fact the quotient of the division is in the EAX register.

```
input   prompt1, string, 40
atod    string                ; -> EAX
mov     number1, eax          ; gallons
input   prompt2, string, 40
atod    string                ; -> EAX
;;;mov     number2, eax          ; miles   Only store to memory if you need this on a later occasion
;;;mov     eax, number2          ; miles
xor     edx, edx              ; Equivalent to `mov edx, 0` (Keep this close to the `div` instruction that follows!)
div     number1               ; miles / gallons
dtoa    mpg, eax
output  resultLxx, mpg
```